# How to use overloaded new operator used in QT namespace

Tags: c++, qt, memory-leaks, operator-overloading, new-operator

I am writing a C++ application which used QT libraries. I want to detect memory leaks in my application and in QT. So, I have overloaded the new and delete operator in my main.cpp using this reference http://lists.trolltech.com/qt-interest/2002-04/msg00933.html, but QT is not using the overloaded operators. Apparently, it appears to be a namespace issue. How to resolve this.

```
int numAllocUnits = 0;
ofstream myLogFile("/root/memLeak.log");

class MemoryLeak_Manav
{
public:
        MemoryLeak_Manav() {
        if (!myLogFile.is_open()) {
                cout << "Unable to open file";
        }
        myLogFile << "Memory Leak Detection log File" << endl;
        printf("Memory Leak Detection On ... ");
        }

public:
        ~MemoryLeak_Manav() {
        myLogFile.close();
        if(numAllocUnits)
                printf("\nError: Memory leak detected: %d\n\n", numAllocUnits);
        else printf("\nNo memory leak detected.\n\n");
        }

public:
   void *operator new [] (size_t size);
   void *operator new (size_t size);
   void operator delete [] (void *p);
   void operator delete (void *p);
};

void * MemoryLeak_Manav::operator new(size_t size)
{
  void *newPtr;
  numAllocUnits++;
  newPtr = malloc(size);
  printf("malloc [%p allocated %d bytes]\n", newPtr, size);
  myLogFile << "malloc [" << newPtr << "allocated" << size << "bytes" << endl;
  return newPtr;
}

void  MemoryLeak_Manav::operator delete(void *p)
{
  numAllocUnits--;
  free(p);
}

void * MemoryLeak_Manav::operator new [] (size_t size)
{
  void *newPtr;
  numAllocUnits++;
  newPtr = malloc(size);
  printf("malloc [%p allocated %d bytes]\n", newPtr, size);
  myLogFile << "malloc [" << newPtr << "allocated" << size << "bytes" << endl;
  return newPtr;
}

void  MemoryLeak_Manav::operator delete [] (void *p)
{
  numAllocUnits--;
  printf("free %p\n", p);
  myLogFile << "free" << p << endl;
  free(p);
}
```

The memLeak.log file is empty and I am not seeing any printf's messages also.

Comment: Wouldn't you need to recompile all the Qt libraries using your new operators for this to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't overload *new* in a library because a library is already compiled. To replace *new* in Qt, you have to obtain Qt sources, put overload in whatever base file of them and then recompile. It isn't as hard as it sounds, by the way.

Answer (score 0):

You made your operators member of a class. Like that, they will only be used within the namespace of the class.

Just define the operators as global operators (without a class) and it should work

Comment: When I make it as global operator it would affect all the libraries. I am getting SIGSEGV when doing like this.

Comment: Well then recompiling Qt is your only chance

Comment: SIGSEGV is coming from libstdc++Starting program: /tuxedo -qws
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
[New Thread 1073878160 (LWP 5916)]
malloc [0x87a008 allocated 4 bytes]

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
[Switching to Thread 1073878160 (LWP 5916)]
0x41359ea0 in std::ostream::sentry::sentry () from /lib/libstdc++.so.6
(gdb)

Answer (score 0):

If you can test it on Linux, then have a look at using the [Valgrind Memcheck](http://valgrind.org/info/tools.html#memcheck) tool.

This provides very detailed information on leaks and bad memory use (double free, corruption, partial free), including full stack traces.

Comment: I am using Linux but I need to cross-compile for ARM-v6 for which Valgrind support is not there.